# SharePoint ajax ValidateUpdateListItem

Tags: ajax, typescript, sharepoint

I would like to post an ajax call to update a list without updating the version. I was told I can make use of the ValidateUpdateListItem() function. However, when I try using it, I have the error: System.ArgumentNullException value cannot be null parameter name: formValues. Here is a code snippet.

```
url: "path/ValidateUpdateListItem()",
  method: "POST",
  contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
  headers: {
    "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose",
    "IF-MATCH": request.ETag,
    "X-HTTP-Method": "MERGE",
    "X-RequestDigest": $('#__REQUESTDIGEST').val()
  },
  data: JSON.stringify({
    "formValues":[
      {
        'Field1': 'value1'
      }
    ],
    'bNewDocumentUpdate': true
  }),
```

Comment: update sharepoint list using jQuery and ajax , check this link [update sharepoint list](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/223771/update-sharepoint-list-using-jquery-and-ajax)

Comment: @MarwenJaffel this will update the version as well, which is what I am trying to avoid.